# How can I carry a unique USER ID generated in Qualtrics to my website for Google Analytics?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, qualtrics

I have a survey on Qualtrics where I want people to answer a few questions, visit website x (a website I developed) and then return to Qualtrics to answer a few more questions about the website.

I figured out how to generate a unique user ID on Qualtrics and THINK I have the right code for implementing Google Analytics with a specific user ID but I know I have to call the ID somehow. My end goal here is to be able to match up website tracking with the Qualtrics user.

In Qualtrics I gave the unique User ID generator a label of "GAnalyticsCode".

So my questions are

1. Would I replace {{USER_ID}} with {{GAnalyticsCode}}
2. Is this the correct method to do this?

   ```
       <script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

     ga('create', 'UA-75902804-1', 'auto');
     ga('send', 'pageview');


   ga('set', 'userId', {{USER_ID}}); // Set the user ID using signed-in user_id.

   </script>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Doing a "set" call after the pageview will not work, since this needs an interaction hit (pageview, event or similar) to be sent to the Google Analytics servers.

More importantly, I do not think UserId is the correct feature to use here. The idea of the UserId feature is to identify users across different devices after they have logged in to your website or application; for this you need a consistent, unique id that ideally is created by your own backend system.

Also a Google Analytics UserID is not exposed in the reports in the interface (with the single exception of the User Explorer report) or via the API.

I suspect you are better of by creating a custom dimension in your property settings (see "Custom Definitions" in the menu), which you might very well call UserId for use in the interface. However it will be addressed in code by the keyword "dimension" and a numeric index.

So this should look like:

```
    <script>
 (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
 (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
 m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
 })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-75902804-1', 'auto');
  ga('set','dimension1',{{USER_ID}}); 
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

and then you can use the custom dimension as secondary dimension in standard reports, you can use it in custom reports, in segments and via the API.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for your time and explanation. If I do generate a unique user ID in Qualtrics named "GAnalyticsCode" would I replace USER_ID with that? I just need to be able to match up users in google analytics with Qualtrics users (no personal information is included from qualtrics).

Comment: Yes, exactly. And as I said the ID needs to be available before you do the actual pageview call (if that is not possible you would need to an event tracking call after you have obtained the id; custom dimensions are not transferred to GA if they are not attached to an interaction). And since I forget to mention it, custom dimensions come in different "scopes" and you probably want "session scope". That way even if you set the dimension only once it is attached to all hits during the visit/session.